# TensorFlow: How to customizingly gather / split a tensor?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, nlp, deep-learning

Please allow me to introduce the background briefly. I am working on a Bi-LSTM-CRF architecture to do a sequence labeling task. Instead of feeding features of individual steps encoded by LSTM into CRF layer, I want to collect feature vectors belonging to the same segment, and averaging them, then send the segment features into CRF. This method was proposed in the paper *Neural Models for Sequence Chunking*.

Now we have a 3D tensor `X` *[batch_size, num_steps, num_features]* and a 2D tensor `Xl` *[batch_size, num_steps]* indicating the IOB labels of the sequence. How could I gather feature vectors belonging to the same segment and transform it to a 4D output tensor *[batch_size, max_segment_num, max_segment_len, num_features]*? The segment boundary is determined by the IOB labels, where *B* indicates the beginning and *I* the inner token.

```
X:
[[v11, v12, v13, v14, v15],
 [v21, v22, v23, v24, v25],
 ...]

IOB labels:
[[B, I, B, I, I],
 [B, B, I, I, B],
 ...]

and the expected output:
[[[v11, v12], [v13, v14, v15]],
 [[v21], [v22, v23, v24], [v25]],
 ...]

with the output, we can compute segment features:
[[u11, u12, 0],  # supposing max_segment_num = 3
 [u21, u22, u23],
 ...]
```

I have investigated a few builtin functions like `tf.gather` or `tf.split`, but to my knowledge none of them supports a custom way. I also looked into the masking functions but didn't figure out how they can help.

I tried manually manipulating the tensor and assign to a newly created 4D tensor, but was stuck there. The tensor X in the definition of the model is a placeholder, and is fed with data in training. Hence, the following statement fails, complaining that we must feed data to the placeholder now.

```
for i in range(batch_size):
    ...
    for j in range(max_segment_num):
        ...
        seg_tensor = tf.gather(X[i,:], rng)  # rng is the segment range
        average_feature = tf.reduce_mean(seg_tensor, axis=0)
        update_op = outputs[i, j, :].assign(average_feature)
        update_op.run()
```

Could anyone give me a hint? How could I solve the problem or is there an easier way using builtin functions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/py_func to make any computation on numpy arrays behave like a native TensorFlow op.